# osx monday date current week bash

Tags: bash, macos, date

I need to get an array of all the dates 
of the current week in BASH 4, in OSX.

I tried to get the monday date, 
but on OSX the date doesn't work the same as Linux (gdate)

The result I need :

```
array=(
'YYYY-MM-DD', # MONDAY
'YYYY-MM-DD', # TUESDAY
'YYYY-MM-DD', # WEDNESDAY
'YYYY-MM-DD', # THURSDAY
'YYYY-MM-DD', # FRIDAY
'YYYY-MM-DD', # SATURDAY
'YYYY-MM-DD') # SUNDAY
```

I'm a novice in bash and tried for 2 hour 
to find something on internet, without success.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

have You tried `man date`?

```
date -v-monday
```

Gets the date adjusted so the weekday is the previous Monday. If it is Monday it gives the current day, so if You discard hours, minutes and seconds You get the date of the first day of the week.

```
date -v-monday +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

gets the format that You requested. To get next dates You can use -v to adjust further, e.g. `date -v-monday -v+1d +'%Y-%m-%d'` gives the date of current week's Tuesday.

So to answer Your question fully:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 0 6)
do
    WEEKDAYS[$i]=`date -v-monday -v+"$i"d +'%Y-%m-%d'`
done;
```

Comment: Or, as a one-liner... `array=( $( for i in {0..6}; do date -v-monday -v+"$i"d +'%Y-%m-%d'; done) )`

Comment: You could keep things within bash using `for i in {0..6}`. Also, rather than mucking with quotes this way, consider `WEEKDAYS[$i]=$(date -v-monday -v+${i}d '+%F')`.

Comment: It's working like a charm :) thank you for your help !